# GRUB installed on two devices, how to select one for boot?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive

Very sorry if this is a duplicate, most of the posts that I read recommend variations of:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
sudo update-grub
```

which I *think* is not my problem here.

---

I have a main HDD on `/dev/sda` where Ubuntu and Windows have been installed for a while. I recently plugged an SSD on `/dev/sdb` and installed Ubuntu on one of the partitions. **GRUB is installed on both devices**, as can be seen from the summary of [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) (nevermind `/dev/sdc`, it's an external drive):

```
                  Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 97 for .
 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb and looks at sector 
    92576960 of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location 
    and looks in partition 97 for .
 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.
```

**I would like to select `/dev/sdb` as the default booting device** (ie, when the computer boots, use the GRUB on `/dev/sdb` instead of currently `/dev/sda`), **is it possible to do this?**

---

More info about the partitions below. My main HDD is a `dos` disk type, whereas I formatted my SSD with `gpt`.

```
Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048    12,290,047    12,288,000  27 Hidden NTFS (Recovery Environment)
/dev/sda2          12,290,048   524,290,047   512,000,000   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3       1,543,925,760 1,953,523,711   409,597,952   5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1,666,809,856 1,789,689,855   122,880,000  83 Linux
...
```

and

```
Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sdb: 978.1 GiB, 1050214588416 bytes, 2051200368 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1                   1 2,051,200,367 2,051,200,367  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sdb1           2,048   270,338,047   270,336,000 Data partition (Linux)
/dev/sdb2     270,338,048   540,674,047   270,336,000 Data partition (Linux)
...
```

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. The main reason why this might be useful to others is that GRUB only gets updated on the new disk; anyone with a similar setup will run into this issue as well. Although I _can_ select my new system from the old GRUB, it is never updated by the system that I use. Changing device boot order allows me to use the GRUB that does get updated.

Answer (score 3):

How you do that is very system-specific. You must enter the firmware setup utility (typically by hitting Del, F2, or some other system-specific key soon after powering on the computer) and locate an option to change the default boot device. Where that option is and what it's called varies from one computer to another; it's not standardized. If you need help with that, you should consult your manual, call the computer's (or motherboard's) manufacturer, or post on a manufacturer-specific forum. You might also want to elaborate on why you want to change the boot disk. Normally, if you boot from a GUID Partition Table (GPT) disk, as your `/dev/sdb` is, in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, that disk must have a [BIOS Boot Partition,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_boot_partition) which your `/dev/sdb` lacks. Thus, it's not clear to me that switching boot disks would be helpful, and it might even create new problems. Understanding why you want to switch boot disks would help us offer you advice that's helpful, rather than advice that helps you dig yourself into a deeper hole.

That said, I recommend you step back a bit first, because there's a bigger issue: *Are you booting in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode or in EFI/UEFI mode?* The output you've posted makes it very likely that you're booting in BIOS mode, but this boot mode is becoming less common every day. The vast majority of computers that shipped with Windows 8 and later pre-installed boot in EFI mode by default, although most of them can be reconfigured to boot in BIOS mode. The reason I think you're *probably* booting in BIOS mode is that your `/dev/sda` is an MBR disk with no sign of an [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) and although your second disk uses GPT, it also does not have an ESP. (BIOS-mode booting is *usually* done from MBR disks, and EFI-mode booting is *usually* done from GPT disks.) Note that the presence of BIOS-mode boot loaders in the first sector of each disk isn't really diagnostic; that can happen if an OS or boot loader is re-installed or if the disk is moved from a BIOS-booting computer to an EFI-booting one.

If a computer boots in EFI mode, it doesn't really boot from a disk in the same sense that a BIOS-based computer boots from a disk. In EFI mode, pointers to boot loader *files* are stored in NVRAM. These *files* can be specified in a way that's similar to the way a BIOS-based computer identifies its boot disks. You could have a dozen boot loader files on one disk and none on another; or several per disk; or one per disk; or any other combination. If you go into it thinking of identifying a "boot disk," you're likely to become confused.

For more information on this question, see [my page on determining boot mode.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootmode.html) As I say, it's likely that your computer is booting in BIOS mode. I'm harping on about this because many people skip past this question and it causes them problems. I'm trying to head off that happening to somebody else who might read this question more than for you, Sheljohn.

One final point is that if your computer is EFI-based, but booting in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, it should be possible to convert it to boot in EFI mode. The hassle of doing this is likely to be greater than the reward, especially if this is a dual-boot computer, as it appears to be; however, since you're looking to change the boot disk, it's conceivable that what you want to do would be better accomplished by changing the boot mode.

Comment: The menu accessed by pressing a key from the booting screen says "UEFI BIOS"; idk whether this corresponds to a legacy mode? I was able to change the order of boot priorities, to move the new device before the old one; the GRUB used is now the one on the new disk.